# Locale matching in dart / flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Go supports it natively: https://go.dev/blog/matchlang

Any equivalent of that in dart / flutter? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`MaterialApp:locale` has a default [matching algorithm](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/basicLocaleListResolution.html), [source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/fb57da5f94/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/app.dart#L124).